# swift tableview delegate method did not response in another class

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, delegates, tableview

i create a new class named xxxtableviewdelegate and i put uitableviewdelgate and uitableviewdatasource into this class, after that, i make

```
tableView1?.delegate = tableView1Delegate
tableView1?.dataSource = tableView1Delegate
```

but  delegate method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

are not called, please help me

these are detail code

```
let tableView1Delegate = ArticleTableViewDelegate()
    tableView1Delegate.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
    tableView1Delegate.headerIdentifier = headerIdentifier
    tableView1Delegate.sectionTitleArray = self.getSectionData()
    tableView1Delegate.cellDatasource = self.getData()

    tableView1 = UITableView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: zkj_width(object: mainScrollView!), height: zkj_height(object: mainScrollView!)), style: .plain)
    mainScrollView?.addSubview(tableView1!)
    tableView1?.delegate = tableView1Delegate
    tableView1?.dataSource = tableView1Delegate
    tableView1?.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView1?.register(ArticleTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: ArticleTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier!, for: indexPath) as! ArticleTableViewCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let aCell = cell as! ArticleTableViewCell
    let model: ArticleModel = cellDatasource![indexPath.row] as! ArticleModel
    aCell.setModel(articleModel: model)
}
```

Comment: In what method do you set the delegates?

Comment: @just_just_just can you show  code.It would be much better to use extensions instead of refactoring your table methods in different class.

Comment: @MaxPevsner UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, some method has worked, but these two method do not work

Comment: @just_just_just it is all explained here-: http://clean-swift.com/refactoring-table-view-data-source-and-delegate-methods/

Comment: @TusharSharma do you mean implement delegate in extensions？but it sounds strange， and not all the method do not work, just these two delegate method do not work

Comment: @just_just_just i shared a link with you just check once and let me know your doubts.

Comment: @TusharSharma thx, but it do not help me, what i use is method 2 in your link. at first, i just put uitableviewdelegate and uiltableviewdatasource in uiviewcontroller, i works well.

Comment: @TusharSharma but i think it is not appropriate from the sight of MVVM, so,  i move this delegate into tableviewdelegate class, and these two method do not wok

Comment: @just_just_just it would be really good if you edit your code -: copy and paste code in answer view then select your code and do-: ctrl + k . Post your answer. Or just copy/paste and post i will edit.

Comment: @just_just_just not in comment mate paste your table view code in answer block.

Comment: @TusharSharma i had past my code

Comment: @just_just_just can you take this on chat ? or are you sure your cell identifier is correct? put a breakpoint and check what is going in .

Comment: @TusharSharma breakpoint just not go to these two method

Comment: @numberOfItems method  is getting called?

Comment: @just_just_just what is ArticleTableViewDelegate()???What code that class hold?

Comment: @TusharSharma do you mean numberOfRows  or  numberOfSection? these two method is getting called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `tableView1Delegate` has scope issue, please make sure it is declared as class instances and not inside function.

```
class YOUR_CONTROLLER {

 var tableView1Delegate : xxxtableviewdelegate

 func YOUR_FUNCTION {
   tableView1 = xxxtableviewdelegate()
   tableView1?.delegate = tableView1Delegate
   tableView1?.dataSource = tableView1Delegate
 }

}
```

Comment: thx，you did help me，but why just some of delegate method not called?

Comment: I believe that should be random behaviour, not only for two delegates.. as delegate reference getting deallocated meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of your xxxtableviewdelegate class.And assign delegate to that object.

```
var object = xxxtableviewdelegate()
yourTableview.datasourse = object
yourTableview.delegate = object
```

You should have implemented UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate protocols in your class.

```
class xxxtableviewdelegate: NSObject,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i do not know how to post code in comments

Comment: @just_just_just Are u calling reload function ??